# Why is my entire render white?

Tags: rendering, materials

I attempted to render my first short movie in Blender (2.68) today, just a 3D structure of a molecule rotating. I imported it using Atomic Blender converted it to a solid object and then rotated the camera around it. When I play the animation in 3D view, it looks fine, but when I render it as an .avi movie, all I see is the background, the molecule is invisible.  It seems that the molecule is just white on white, so I need to add textures to the molecule.

Is there a way to make it look like it does in 3D view without having to add the textures to every atom manually?

I uploaded the file here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=21234281675843448966

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on the file that you uploaded and your question *(which I have now edited accordingly)*, you are actually asking about material settings.

The model *does* have materials. The problem was that the *World* color, specifically the *Ambient* color was set to full white and was overriding everything and making the entire scene look as such.

Here is your render with your current settings.

[image]

Here is the same render with the *Ambient* color set to full white and the others changed to show the contrast.

[image]

Here is your render with *only* the world settings changed *(to the default settings)* and a hemi lamp instead of the point lamp that you had to make it a bit brighter.

[image]